# In a trace decorator how to retrieve the line number of the return statement that returned from the decorated function?

Tags: python-3.x, logging, return, decorator, inspection

In Python 3.5 I'm writing a metaclass that adds trace decorators (loggging of method entry and exit) to all methods. I'm using logging.getLogRecordFactory()/setLogRecordFactory() to modify some fields in the LogRecord before calling the log function, especially I want to modify "lineno". For the entry trace I'm using co_firstlineno, for the exit trace due to an exception, I'm using tb_lineno of the traceback.

How can I retrieve the line number of the return statement (there may be more than one such statements) that returned from the decorated function or the line number of the last statement of that function in case it returned without a return statement?

Answer (score 0):

sys.settrace() solved my problem.

Here the complete code of my metaclass which adds entry/exit traces to all methods of the using class:

```
import functools
import inspect
import logging
import sys
import types

TRACE = 5
logging.addLevelName(TRACE, "TRACE")


def _trace(self, msg, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.isEnabledFor(TRACE):
        self._log(TRACE, msg, args, **kwargs)

logging.Logger.trace = _trace


def get_logger(func, cls=None):
    logger_name = "%s.%s" % (
        func.__module__,
        func.__qualname__ if cls is None else
        "%s.%s" % (
            cls.__qualname__,
            func.__qualname__))
    return logging.getLogger(logger_name)


def trace(func, cls=None):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        old_record_factory = logging.getLogRecordFactory()

        code = inspect.unwrap(func).__code__
        pathname = code.co_filename
        funcname = func.__name__

        def create_record_factory(lineno):
            def record_factory(*args, **kwargs):
                record = old_record_factory(*args, **kwargs)
                record.lineno = lineno
                record.pathname = pathname
                record.funcName = funcname
                return record
            return record_factory

        logger = get_logger(func, cls)

        exception_line = None
        return_line = None

        def call_tracer(frame, event, arg):
            if event == 'call' and frame.f_code == code:
                return exit_tracer

        def exit_tracer(frame, event, arg):
            nonlocal exception_line, return_line

            if event == 'return':
                return_line = frame.f_lineno
            elif event == 'exception':
                exception_line = frame.f_lineno
            return exit_tracer

        def trace_wrapper(msg, lineno):
            logging.setLogRecordFactory(create_record_factory(lineno))
            logger.trace(msg)
            logging.setLogRecordFactory(old_record_factory)

        signature = inspect.signature(func)
        bound_args = signature.bind(*args, **kwargs)

        trace_wrapper(
            ">>> %s(%s)" % (
                func.__name__,
                ", ".join(
                    "%s=%r" % item
                    for item in bound_args.arguments.items())),
            code.co_firstlineno)

        old_tracer = sys.gettrace()
        try:
            sys.settrace(call_tracer)
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            trace_wrapper(
                "<<< %s returns %r" % (func.__name__, result),
                return_line)
            return result
        except Exception as exc:
            trace_wrapper(
                "<<< %s raises %r in line %d" % (
                    func.__name__, exc, exception_line),
                return_line)
            raise
        finally:
            sys.settrace(old_tracer)
    return wrapper


class LoggingMeta(type):

    def __init__(cls, cls_name, bases, cls_dict, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(cls_name, bases, cls_dict, **kwargs)
        for attr_name, attr_value in cls.__dict__.items():
            if isinstance(attr_value, classmethod):
                setattr(cls, attr_name, classmethod(
                    trace(attr_value.__func__)))
            elif isinstance(attr_value, staticmethod):
                setattr(cls, attr_name, staticmethod(
                    trace(attr_value.__func__)))
            elif isinstance(attr_value, types.FunctionType):
                setattr(cls, attr_name, trace(attr_value))
```